# IIS Pipeline Postback detection

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, httpmodule, pipeline

How can I use the IIS HttpApplication object in a module to detect if the request is a postback?  This is for a www / ssl redirecting module so we want to detect whether or not it is postback as soon as possible, preferably before page execution.  This code will need to run on IIS6 and IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by just checking the request method to see if it was POST instead of GET.